# Combining CSV files from one folder into one file through MS Acces s vba

Tags: vba, excel, csv, ms-access

Hi there so I finished the section of a program which calculates and exports a csv with results. (ends up about 1600 csv files) each having only 1 column and between 20 and 0 rows. I would like my MS Access VBA program to join them together into one larger CSV. So Same header only once at the top of the new file.

The program i have so far seems to fall over at the part where it tries to import the Reg. Number of the File.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
MTH = Format(Date, "mmm")
UserInput = InputBox("Enter Country Code")
Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

    Application.Echo False

    'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
    strSourcePath = "Q:\CCNMACS\AWD" & CTRY

    If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

    'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
    strDestPath = "Q:\CCNMACS\AWDFIN"

    If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

    strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        If Cnt = 1 Then
            r = 1
        Else
            r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
            If Cnt > 1 Then
                Line Input #1, strData
            End If
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, strData
                x = Split(strData, ",")
                For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                    wks.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c)) 'Error is here: Run time error '91': Object variable or With Block variable not set
                Next c
                r = r + 1
            Loop
        Close #1
        Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.Echo True

    If Cnt = 0 Then _
        MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation
```

Comment: You'll need to share an example of the data, and how it's being combined. If I'm understanding correctly what you need to do (ie append several files into one "long" one), then there are several ways to do this without VBA.

Comment: Between [tag:excel] and [tag:ms-access] this has been asked 3 times today alone.

Comment: So pretty much the file is very basic just has the header in Column A as "Reg. Number" and under that youd get between 20 and 0 numerical entries that are up to 9 characters long

Comment: @Jeeped i had looked for something like my problem but i could only find examples of people doing it it in Dos, python and R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't absolutely definitive as to what you're trying to do, but if I understand correctly, you just need to append several files to the end of each other, to make *"one big CSV"*.

If that's true then there are several ways to do this a lot simpler than using VBA.  **`.CSV`** files are just plain text files with comma's separating each field, and a `.CSV` filename extension.

Personally I would use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (I assume it's capable of this; it does everything else), or perhaps even easier, I would use the Windows **Command Prompt**.

---

**Let's say you have a folder with files:**

```
File1.csv
File2.csv
File3.csv
...etc
```

- Open the Windows Command Prompt. (One way is with the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>Windows key + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd` and hit Enter.)
- Change directory with to the file location using `cd` (same as `ChDir`).
  (For example, you might use `cd c:\users\myFolder`,
  and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- To combine all `CSV`'s in the folder into one, you could use a command like:

  ```
  copy *.csv combinedfile.csv
  ```

***That's it!***

---

A file is created named `combinedfile.csv`. You can open in Excel or a text editor (like Notepad) to double-check it and adjust manually if necessary.

Obviously there are many ways you could vary the command, like if you only wanted the files that start with the word `File` you could use:

```
copy file*.csv combinedFile.csv
```

[image: img]

Comment: Yes. DOS rules.

Comment: Tried that and it worked a charm. Only thing is that it combines all the headings together as well but seeing as they're all the same thats a quick filter and fixed. Thanks again

Comment: Is it possible to call this DOS maybe as a command in VBA? Like a function. The people who would call this program almost certainly wouldnt know how to use DOS at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub Import()

        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = True

        ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
        ' contains the EXCEL files
        strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "Table1"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile
              DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

See the links below for additional details pertaining to this topic.

https://anthonysmoak.com/2018/04/10/how-to-fix-an-import-specification-error-in-microsoft-access/

https://www.oakdome.com/programming/MSAccess_ExportSpecifications_TransferText_To_CSV.php